# How would I create a ribbon around a hat?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

Im trying to make a ribbon to wrap around a top hat that im making that it looks natural and has like creases and stuff and with a little bit hanging off the back.

[image: Kind of like the hat that the mad hatter wears:]

Thank you! :)

Comment: There are really two ways to go about this. You can sculpt it, or you can simulate it.

Comment: Im kind of new to using blender.. Which simulator would you suggest?

Comment: cloth simulator

Comment: Probably you will need to use both ways together - first model rough shape of the ribbon and add cloth simulator on it and set it up, and second apply simulator and sculpt the result. See also http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=ribbon

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to create the ribbon portion? I am making the same hat.

Answer (score 3):

Alright!

I experimented quite a while for this. Cloth sim seemed to be a good alternative, especially **[this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q06lPp2PNG4)**.

But eventually I found that modelling by hand the results are better, at least for the ribbon:

[image]

Start by selecting a portion of the hat:

[image]

Duplicate it <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Scale it along the normals <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Separate it <kbd>P</kbd>. Assign new material to it if you wish:

[image]

Add some edgeloops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Deselect all <kbd>A</kbd>. In the vertex mode, go to **'Select'** > **'Random'**. Enter **15%**. Deselect the top and bottom edgeloop, or the edges of the ribbon:

[image]

Slide the vertices all the way down <kbd>GG</kbd>. Select all <kbd>A</kbd> and in <kbd>W</kbd> select **'Remove doubles'**:

[image]

Add some horizontal edgeloops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

Select all <kbd>A</kbd> and deselect the boundaries or edges of the ribbon:

[image]

Go to **'Mesh'** > **'Transform'** > **'Randomize'**. I used these values:

[image]

Select all <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd> > **'Smooth'**

Then, select horizontal edgeloops in edge mode one by one and slide them <kbd>GG</kbd> in order to form tighter creases. Also scale them by their normal <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in order to make nooks and crevices, or hills and valleys, or something like that:

[image]
[image]

Maybe add some more horizontal edgeloops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, maybe select all and smooth again <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd> > **'Smooth'**. Maybe select an edgeloop and add bevel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. This is the creative part, go nuts. Finally, add a Solidify modifier (and move it to be the topmost in the modifier stack) to give it some thickness:

[image]

[image]

That's it.

I hope this was helpful :)

**[.blend](https://github.com/manujarvinen/Blends/raw/master/Hat_Ribbon_Cloth_Sim_And_Modelled.blend)**

In the .blend file there is also my simulation test, which doesn't look bad either (maybe it's even better for some situations), especially after you apply some of the methods mentioned here to the simulated mesh. Just play the timeline <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to see the simulation in action. After that, it's handy to **Apply** the **Cloth modifier** and continue modelling from there:

[image]